# Compiler error when using abstract types

Tags: scala

I'm trying to implement a "protocol helper" trait that is responsible for matching up `Prompts` and `Responses`. The eventual goal is to have an `object` that defines the various Prompt and Response classes as subclasses of a sealed trait, then have a `class` that mixes in the `ProtocolSupport` trait for that Protocol object. The problem is that my current approach won't compile, even though I'm fairly sure it *should*.

Here's a distilled version of what I've got:

```
trait Protocol {
    type Response
    type Prompt <: BasePrompt

    trait BasePrompt {
        type Data
        def validate(response: Response): Validated[Data]
    }
}

trait ProtocolSupport[P <: Protocol] {
    def foo(prompt: P#Prompt, response: P#Response) = {
        // compiler error
        prompt.validate(response)
    }
}
```

The compiler doesn't like the `response` as an argument to `prompt.validate`:

```
[error]  found   : response.type (with underlying type P#Response)
[error]  required: _4.Response where val _4: P
[error]                 prompt.validate(response)
[error]                                 ^
```

This isn't very helpful.. it seems to say that it wants a `P.Response` but that's exactly what I'm giving it, so what's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiler absolutely right. It is a family polymorphism and compiler expect type from one family (path depended type).
It need to be look like that:

```
//dependent method type need to be used
//it guaranty that prompt & response from the same hierarchy      
def foo(proto : P)(prompt: proto.Prompt, response: proto.Response) = {
```

Because in your example you can call method with with instances of prompt & respond from different hierarchy (type paths). It look like that you can call `foo` method with `prompt` from `HTTPProtocol` but `response` from `JSONProtocol`.

**Update:**

Dependent method type released in [SCALA 2.10 series](http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2013/03/13/release-notes-v2.10.1.html)